# Python 2.7 - Tkinter - text widget and gridding

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm having trouble with a widget's gridding. Using the tk module, I built a notebook with tabs that contain Frames. In this frame, there's a bunch of widgets. However, there's a problem where the widget expands well beyond the 1x1 grid I gave it.

[image: the widget expands well beyond 1x1 on the grid]

Here's the code for this:

```
self.dataGenerationFrame = Frame(self.tab)
        noteEntry = Text(self.dataGenerationFrame, borderwidth=2, relief=SUNKEN)
        noteEntry.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, sticky = 'W')
        goalValEntry = Spinbox(self.dataGenerationFrame, from_=0, to=10)
        goalValEntry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky ='W')
```

What's going on? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you change the width option of the text widget to something...a lot smaller. It has a default value of 80 I believe

Comment: @atlasologist that worked, but I'd much rather use the gridding option, as it's worked in the past.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain more? Like, do you want to shrink the text widget, or expand the frame to fit the text? And what has worked vs. what didn't. I'm just not really sure what answer you're looking for.